# Testing a promise inside an async function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to write a jest test to test a promise that runs within a async function. I'm having a hard time finding resources that describe how to do that.

Below is what I have:

```
const foo = async (client) => {
  const update = data => {};

  await client.query({
    query: QUERY,
    variables: {
      x: xVal,
      y: yVal,
    },
  }).then(response => {
    update({ response });
  }).catch(error => {
    update({ [] });
  });
}

...
fetch: ()  => {
    foo(client)
},
```

Essentially I need to test `fetch()` and then confirm that `update()` ran in both the success and error case within `foo()`.

Comment: `update` is an internal function inside of `foo`, so it's an implementation detail that seems irrelevant to the external interface contract for `foo`. If it were a callback or an external dependency like `fetch`, it'd make sense to mock it and assert it was called in both happy and sad paths, but it's not.

Comment: Please include complete code, some variables are lost